# Bluez-can't start bluetooth.service

Tags: services, bluetooth, bluez

i have downgraded my bluez version from 5 to 4.79.First i uninstalled bluez5 with sudo apt-get purge and then i did sudo apt-get autoremove. Then i wget the tar file and did the classic ./configure , make , sudo make install without errors.

The problem is that:
`$ systemctl status bluetooth` output is:

```
*bluetooth.service 
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

So when i try to `$ sudo systemctl start bluetooth` the output is:

```
Failed to start bluetooth.service : Unit bluetooth.service failed to load: No such file or directory
```

`$ bluetoothd -v` output:

4.79

How can i start the bluetooth service and why is the bluetooth.service file is missing? I am new to linux and i run bluez on rp1 with raspbian jessie. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
Failed to enable unit: Unit file bluetooth.service does not exist.
```

I was getting above error so I tried to install all bluez package and it worked.

```
sudo apt-get install bluez*
```

after installation, I have enabled Bluetooth

```
$ sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable bluetooth

$ sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

Comment: I remember trying that and it wasn't the solution. As a workaround, I end up not using bluez at all.

Comment: It's the only thing that worked for me using a dongle with Bluetooth 5.0 (on a PI). Thanks a lot!